# In android default browser, I use -webkit-transform and scale to zoom in a svg file.It becomes Pixelated and blurred，how to deal with it

Tags: android, css, html, svg

In android default browser, I use -webkit-transform and scale to zoom in a svg file.
It becomes Pixelated  and blurred. how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting width on SVG ,calculate the width of SVG after it scales and set its maximum width as width.That might help..